# regex a before b with and without whitespaces

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I am trying to find all the string which include 'true' when there is no 'act' before it.

An example of possible vector:

```
vector = c("true","trueact","acttrue","act true","act really true")
```

What I have so far is this:

```
grepl(pattern="(?<!act)true", vector, perl=T, ignore.case = T)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

what I'm hopping for is

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
grepl(pattern="^(.(?<!act))*?true", vector, perl=T, ignore.case = T)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

- `^`: start of the string
- `.`: matches any character
- `(?<=)`: negative lookbehind
- `act`: matches `act`
- `*?`: matches `.(?<!act)` between 0 and unlimited times
- `true`: matches true

---

see [here](https://regex101.com/r/oBy4yl/1) for the regex demo

Comment: What start of the string is doing? what is happening when I don't use it? (the sources on regex are really messy, hence my basic lack of knowledge!)

Comment: @Pedro ``^`` ensures that there is no ``act`` before ``true``. From the beginning of the string, we check that each character is not preceded by ``act``, until we reach ``true``. If we do not put ``^``, there will necessarily be a match starting from the word ``act`` (not included).

Answer (score 1):

May be this works - i.e. to `SKIP` the match when there is 'act' as preceding substring but match `true` otherwise

```
grepl("(act.*true)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\btrue", vector, 
     perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```